# Facing problem in Variable Transformation in VS Code snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code, replace, path, vscode-snippets

I'm having the below code of a global-snippet of [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

```json
"prints formated path": {
    "prefix": "pp",
    "body": [
        "$BLOCK_COMMENT_START",
        "File Path ->     \"${TM_FILEPATH/\\///g}\"",
        "$BLOCK_COMMENT_END",
    ],
    "description": "prints path"
},
```

and the output of the above snippet is

```py
"""
File Path ->     "D:\tp\New folder (6)\4. Chapter 4 Packaging\my_package\test.py"
"""
```

and the expected output is

```py
"""
File Path ->     "D:/tp/New folder (6)/4. Chapter 4 Packaging/my_package/test.py"
"""
```

Actually I want to replace '**\**' with '**/**'

After searching too much on the web I found [this page](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/definitive-guide-to-snippets-visual-studio-code/#:%7E:text=6.-,Transformations,-Transformations%20can%20be) which talks about [*Variable Transformation in VS Code*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variable-transforms) but it didn't help me.
If you know the solution to the problem please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the parsing of the regex, you have to add a capture group to recognize the backslash and you have to escape the replace slash

```
  "prints formated path": {
    "prefix": "pp",
    "body": [
        "$BLOCK_COMMENT_START",
        "File Path ->     \"${TM_FILEPATH/(\\\\)/\\//g}\"",
        "$BLOCK_COMMENT_END",
    ],
    "description": "prints path"
  }
```